# Pass javascript "this" parameter when calling javascript function via web-browser control

Tags: javascript, c#, parameters, webbrowser-control, call

I'm trying to run a simple javascript function via a c# application using a web-browser,
the issue is that the javascript function uses the "this" parameter

```
onclick="submit(this);"
```

And the full html button code:

```
<input type="submit" name="NextButton" value="Done" onclick="onsubmit(this);" id="NextButton" class="btn">
```

How can I use this function via C# as this is, from my understanding, maintained by the executing javascript. Is it possible? If so, how can I go about doing it?

Here is the line I'm using:

```
browser.Document.InvokeScript("onsubmit", new string[] { "#NextButton" });
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I have no idea about C# but due to the fact how inline event handlers work, you can't use `submit` as function name if the button is inside a form.

Comment: @FelixKling The method is actually onsubmit, I must have removed that on accident